# unwind segue vs. popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: swift2, unwind-segue, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a mapview that is connected to several viewControllers.

I needed to implement an 'unwind' from another button (as opposed to just the back button), so I used:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

My question is: as the above works, should I even bother trying to implement unwind in code using `prepareForUnwind` and `canPerformUnwindSegueAction` in the parent view controller + ctrl-drag from the viewController to exit in Storyboard? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically if you are just `dimissing` a presented `UIViewController` or popping a `UIViewController` from the navigation stack,you don't need to use unwind segues although it does the same for you.

But think of a case where there are `UINavigationControllers` **A,B,C** and then a `RootViewController` **R**

Then think of a condition

```
 (Present) R -> A
 (Push) AR -> XVController
 (Push)XVController -> B
 (Present)BR-> YVContoller
...and so on..
```

Now if you want to go back to YVController to your project RootViewController where you just started up.There is no way as `popToRootViewController` pops to the navigation stack of the B `UINavigationController`.Now what you do..Either use delegate or change window RootViewController *which is not a good idea*.

So you need to use unwind segue to overcome this.. A sample [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dTvD1JbkgBVEotVHRJY0dFWGs/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate the power of using it..